# delete PersistentVolumeClaim in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a PersistentVolumeClaim in Kubernetes cluster. I would like to delete and recreate it, in my development environment to, in this way, sort of reset some services that use it.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: kafka-disk1
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: managed-premium
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Sorry for this noob question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- the imperative way:

  `$ kubectl delete pvc kafka-disk1`
- the declarative way:

  you can label your resources , and then do `kubectl apply -f` with prune option , and label , so when you delete the yaml from the manifest directory , kubectl will contact the api server and compare the resources on the file and in the cluster , and the missing resource in the files will be deleted

Comment: hmm , try the declarative way. :)